# Clearing will-change CSS property

Tags: css, will-change

What is the correct value for 'clearing' the `will-change` CSS property? I tried using `'auto'`, but according to Chrome Dev Tools (in both the current version of Chrome (46), and Canary (48)) that's an invalid property value.

[image]

Comment: [This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/will-change) can be helpful.

Comment: But the initial value of `will-change` [*is* `auto`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-will-change/#will-change).

Comment: @alirezasafian Well, that page claims the initial value is 'auto', which seems to be an invalid value (at least according to Chrome Dev Tools.)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/will-change

Answer (score 0):

According to auto-complete in Firefox, it seems to be `'unset'`.

[image]

Comment: The `unset` value for `will-change` is equivalent to `initial`. The three values you see are all CSS-wide keyword values. If `auto` doesn't work, see if `initial` does - for whatever Chrome thinks the initial value of the property is anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to set it as `auto` which is the default 'initial' state like so:

```
this.style.willChange = 'auto';
```

Alternatively try:

```
Will-Change: initial;
```

Please note that Chrome only supports will-change as of Chrome 36+ so if you use a browser version before that then it will not recognise it. Will-Change is currently not supported in IE, Edge or Safari:

http://caniuse.com/#feat=will-change

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. Both current Chrome (46) and Canary (48) reports a will-change property of 'auto' as invalid. If it really is invalid it won't do me any good using javascript to set it, as the value is still invalid.

Comment: Try Will-change:initial instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to the spec, the initial value is `auto`:

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-will-change-1/#will-change

So this is likely a Chrome-Dev-Tools bug.